# How to add multiple nested object keys in Dexie?

Tags: dexie

I'm in a loop where I add several new keys (about 1 to 3) to an indexeddb row.
The dexie table looks like:

```
{
    event_id: <event_id>
    <event data>
    groups: {
       <group_id> : { group_name: <name>, <group data> }
    }
}
```

I add the keys using Dexie's modify() callback, in a loop:

```
newGroupNr++
db.event.where('event_id').equals(event_id).modify(x => x.groups[newGroupNr]=objData)
```

objData is a simple object containing some group attributes.

However, this way when I add two or three groups, only one group is actually written to the database. I've tried wrapping them in a `transaction()`, but no luck.

I have the feeling that the issue is that the `modify()`-calls overlap each other, as they run asynchronously. Not sure if this is true, nor how to deal with this scenario.

Dexie modify():
https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()

Related:
[Dexie : How to add to array in nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907820/dexie-how-to-add-to-array-in-nested-object)

EDIT: I found the problem, and it's not related to Dexie. However, I do not fully understand why this fix works, perhaps something to do with that in javascript everything is passed by reference instead of value? My theory is that the integer newGroupNr value was passed as reference, and in the next iteration of the loop, before Dexie was able to finish, incremented, causing effectively two creations of the same key. This fixed it:

```
newGroupNr++
let newGroupNrLocal = newGroupNr
db.event.where('event_id').equals(event_id).modify(x => x.groups[newGroupNrLocal]=objData)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Safari that hits Dexie's modify method in dexie versions below 3. If that's the case, upgrade dexie to latest. If it's not that, try debugging and nailing down when the modify callbacks are actually happening. A transaction won't help as all IDB operations go through transactions anyway and the modification you do should by no means overwrite the other.

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome, not Safari, so that's not it.